# Algorithm correctness using loop invariants

Tags: loops, invariants

I have to prove the correctness of the algorithm below using loop invariants.
It takes two numbers represented as arrays ( reverse order: 1579 -> [9 7 5 1] ), process their multiplication and return the result as an array.

```
ArraysMultiplication(x,y,n)
In: x, y — the numbers represented as arrays
In: n — the length of arrays
Out:  p (the array that contains the multiplication result)
for i = 0; 2n - 1 do
    p[i] = 0
end for
for i = 0; n - 1 do
    remainder = 0
    for j = 0; n - 1 do
        value = x[j] * y[i] + remainder + p[j + i]
        p[j + i] = value mod 10
        remainder = value div 10
    end for
    p[n + i] = remainder
end for
return p
```

I don't really understand what should loop invariants do for this algorithm.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A loop invariant reduces each iteration of a loop to a simpler predicate, and in turn, you might be able to say something about the loop based on the loop invariant. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried something like p(k) = p(k-1) + y*x[k]*10^(k-1), where p(k) is the result array after the step k. But I'm almost sure that it is not correct because I know that I must use a second invariant for the loop inside the big one.